# HTML form cannot post file content

Tags: html

I'd like to post file to server by html form below:

```
<form action="http://localhost:8000/upload/file=1.txt" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="file">
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

And the HTTP header is below after click button "Send":

**Response Headers**

- HTTP/1.0 200 OK
- Date: Tue, 11 Aug 2015 08:35:28 GMT
- Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.4.3
- X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
- Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

**Request Headers**

- POST /upload/file=1.txt HTTP/1.1
- Host: localhost:8000
- User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:39.0)
  Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0
- Accept:
  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
- Accept-Language: de
- Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
- Referer: http://localhost:8083/
- Connection: keep-alive

**Request Headers From Upload Stream**

- Content-Length   48
- Content-Type multipart/form-data;
  boundary=---------------------------121841334829646

But it seems the file content can never be posted. Only the "-----------------------------121841334829646--" be posted to server. How can the file content be posted to server by html form?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form controls can only be successful if they have a `name`.

> ```
> <input type="file">
> ```

should be

```
<input type="file" name="my-file">
```